# How to parse a json string to an array of strings in dataframe

Tags: arrays, json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Scala and just spent 3 hours trying to figure out how to parse a simple json string to an array of strings inside a dataframe.

Here's my code:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
...
emailsDf.select(from_json($"emails", Array[String])).show()
```

The `emailsDf` dataframe has one column called "emails", and in each row it is a json string of an array of strings: `["test1@mail.com", test2@mail.com, ...]`

Here's the error message I got:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   missing argument list for method apply in object Array Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected. You can make this conversion explicit by writing apply _ or apply(*)(*) instead of apply.

Comment: I need to parse the string into an array. from `"['email1', 'email2']"` into `['email1', 'email2']`

Comment: The previous one is just a string, but the later one is an array

Comment: emailsDf is a dataframe, and in each row under the colume "emails", the structure like this: `"['email1', 'email2', 'email3', ...]"` which is a string. And I need to transfer all of them into arrays of strings

Comment: There is a problem with this `from_json` that is not the way this function works. You need to parse with a StructType or a DataType. But there is a problem with this function for your case that will be solved in the next versions: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22228 I suggest you to use UDFs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [UDF](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-udfs.html) to convert the string into an array. A small example with some test data:

```
val df = Seq("[email1, email2, email3]", "[email4, email5]").toDF("emails")

val split_string_array = udf((emails: String) => {
  emails.substring(1, emails.length - 1).split(",").map(_.trim)
})

val df2 = df.withColumn("emails", split_string_array($"emails"))
```

`df2` will now contain a single column with an array

```
root
 |-- emails: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

as wanted.